# Can OS X Lion Server users be authenticated to an external LDAP server and also have access to Profile Manager?

Tags: ldap, mac-osx-server, user-accounts, mobile-devices, lion

I am researching whether the Profile Manager included in Apple's Lion Server edition is a viable option to use to manage iOS devices OTA in our organization. While going through the documentation for Profile Manager and Lion server, I became a bit confused about something I hope someone here can easily clear up for me that is probably just a matter of me misreading something.

I know Lion server can be configured to authenticate users against another ldap server, which is great, but for some reason while reading I got the impression that these users would only have access to Wiki, and **not** the Profile Manager, meaning they could not enroll devices. It sounded like only local users or users defined on its own ldap server could access all features and services available. And now, if I am wrong about this, then the second issue would be user access. Everyone in our ldap should have access as long as they can authenticate. Can every user be allowed to access the Profile Manager even if I do not define each and every one on the Lion server?

Is there anyone already using Profile Manager in an environment with an external ldap server and authenticating users against it for purposes of device enrollment? (External to the lion server, but internal to the org.)

Reason for asking is $50 is much better than the $100-$200K for an MDM solution from a third party so I am trying my best to make this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article that seems to support the theory that users on a third party ldap server (not local), can use Profile Manager, with some additional configuration.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4837